# New column based on a filter and an index of multiples columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

I've been trying to search/think about an answer, probably with a melt or stack, but still can't seem to do it.

Here's my DF :

```
d = {'type' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'company' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 'value type': ['value car','value car','value car','value car','value car', 'value train','value train','value train','value train','value train',],
 'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55] }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Here is what I want (I have the array on the left, I want the one on the right):
[image]
As you can see, I want a new column "train value" based on the combination (type,company)

Something like

```
for each row : 
    if (df['value type'] == 'value train'):
        #and (type,company) is the same
        df['train value'] = df['value']
        remove row
```

For example, the company A from type 1 will have a new value in a new column for its train value.
Is there a way to do this properly ?

EDIT::: There was a good answer but I didn't explain myself clearly. I want only a new column with only "one value type". For example my new DF :

```
d = {'type' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'company' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 'month' : ['jan', 'feb', 'marc', 'apr', 'may', 'jan', 'feb', 'marc', 'apr', 'sep'],
 'business' : ['business1', 'business2', 'business3', 'business4', 'business5', 'business6', 'business7', 'business8', 'business9', 'business10'], 
 'value time': ['past', 'past', 'past', 'past', 'present', 'present', 'present', 'present', 'future', 'future'],
 'value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.11, 0.21, 0.31, 0.41, 0.45, 0.55] }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Heres what I want this time : [image]

If possible, only the values with the "present" will be in the new column. Something like

```
if df['value time'] == 'present' then add to new column
```

Comment: Can you paste your dataframe instead of putting a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

You should pivot your dataframe:

```
company_to_type = df.set_index('company')['type'].to_dict()
df = df.pivot(index='company', columns='value type', values='value').reset_index()
df['type'] = df.company.map(company_to_type)
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df = df[['type', 'company', 'value train', 'value car']]
```

and you'll get

```
   type company  value train  value car
0     1       A         0.15        0.1
1     2       B         0.25        0.2
2     3       C         0.35        0.3
3     4       D         0.45        0.4
4     5       E         0.55        0.5
```

Comment: hello, thanks a lot for ur comment. It helps me understand the point of pivot. I just have a problem, i have a lot more columns for my "indexation" (i don't know if that makes sense, for example we have (type,company,month,date) and i want to add the values where the "value time" is equal to a certain value. I have updated my post, which explains the problem better could you help me once more time please ?